# Are there any free datasets on Japanese company names available?

Tags: data-request, companies, japan, japanese

Are there any datasets that contains Japanese Company names?

For example, ASICS Corporation's Japanese company name is "アシックス". If the datasets contains other information about the company it is fine, as long as it has the company name in Japanese characters.

Comment: @Pluviophile hmm I don't really understand what those are suppose to do

Answer (score 0):

You can scrape the following Wikipedia webpage : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_companies_of_Japan